# Visual Studio 2012 - Now exiting silently after splashscreen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've had my current install of VS2012 for a couple of months it, and the Windows 7 x64 OS I run it under is patched and up-to-date. Today (Monday) I arrived at my desk and started it up as I always do. It gets as far as the splash screen and then silently quits. I can see the `devenv` process in Task Manager for about 15seconds before it decides to kill itself.

I have tried running VS in both `Safe` and `Diagnostic` modes and get the same result. Can anyone suggest steps I could take to troubleshoot this or a fix? VS is my bread-and-butter and I've been without it for a day. Unfortunately my work pc doesn't have an SSD so I'd be looking at a couple of hours of downtime if I had to re-install VS completely....

Comment: Turn on the [`/Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241272.aspx), see what you get.

Comment: You try PC reboot? Check also windows event log.

Comment: I rebooted (many, many times). There doesn't seem to be anything in the logs. I tried running ProcMon from sysinternals.com too. It couldn't get a handle on anything after the devenv.exe process exits.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Monitoring Silent Process Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj602791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tab of gflags, you will be able to get the dump of devenv and the dump of other process who killed the devenv. Then you may have some clue on why the VS exit silently.

Hope it helps.